# Exceeded soft memory limit of 1024 MB after servicing 0 requests total

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**Before anyone mark this question as duplicate**, there are a few issues that makes it different to me.

1. It is **shocking** to to see this error report indicating **Zero requests!!** with **1024 MBs (1GB!!)** yet I made a post request with text payload that **cannot even reach 1KB**.

Error:`Exceeded soft memory limit of 1024 MB with 1059 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml`

**Note:** nothing else is using this server!! **No cron jobs, no deamons,** nothing I expect to consume memory. Before, I have done a lot of code optimizations for this server and it has actually been idle. Only serving button click requests from my phone without background service in the app(One app by one user).

**YAML file:** I use;

```
# [START gae_quickstart_yaml]
runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: F4_1G
# [END gae_quickstart_yaml]
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.9
```

Question:

1. What is is the problem?
2. If I take this to production (given the issue is solved), can it handle 5000-10000 users making 20-30 requests per day? if not, I would really appreciate a sample configuration for this number of users. It is my first time to host on **Google app engine/Google cloud**

**EDIT:** Endpoint code:

```js
router.post('/endP', (req, res) => {
    let options = req.body.userdata;
    let isResponded = false;
    //simply inserting to DB with knex
    db_helper.insert(con.knex, options).then(async (s) => {
        isResponded=true;
        let reply = JSON.stringify(s);
        const message_content = {
                data: {
                body:reply
                },
                android: {
                    ttl: 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 28, // 4 weeks
                    priority: 'high',
          
                },
                topic:"myTopic"
            };
            //FCM notification
            await firebase.sendMessage(message_content);
            res.status(200).send(encryptor.encrypt(reply)).end();
    }).catch(err => {
        if (!isResponded) {
            let errr = err;
            res.status(500).send('Failed').end();
        }
        return null
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code / data is using 1059 MB. The first step is to edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @JohnHanley Check out the added code please, a code that simple is consuming one GB!!!

Comment: Add ALL your code not just part.

Comment: the rest of the code that was related to this endpoint is simply my database(knex) access configuration with private credentials that wouldn't consume One GB  even if I implemented it in 40 files or initialized it 50 times

Comment: When you post a question on SO, you should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. If you do not want to post all your code, reduce the code to the minimum that reproduces your problem and post that.

Answer (score 2):

How much memory does it consume when run locally?
In case you can't post all of your code, please post the result of a memory profile when it is running
I know stackdriver have a profiler in beta which could be useful to track down what is happening https://cloud.google.com/profiler/